# What is the proper way to add an API-only controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to add an API endpoint to my Rails (version 5.0.1) application built around the Getting Started [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), but when I attempt to create a Controller, it ends up creating erbs and other cruft I suspect I don't need for an API-only controller.

What is the correct command to issue?

I attempted `rails generate controller api index show new edit create update destroy` with and without a `--api` option.

I would welcome links to good guides to follow; this is my first Rails project and I've only found good guides for creating an API only application or a web only application, not how to add API endpoints to your existing application.

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. I'd suggest looking up [API versioning](http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/api-versioning-with-rails-4) before beginning to write an API only controller. Anyways a common standard for API controllers is to use appropriate name-spacing. So if your controller is to be called `StatsController`, the hierarchy should be `app/controllers/api/v1/stats_controller.rb`. Use `v2`, `v3` and so on for more versions of your api. Goes without saying that your `StatsController` should now look like:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class StatsController < ApplicationController
      .
      .
    end
  end
end
```